# How to protect pages with unique passwords using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I need to set up password protection on pages using Laravel, each page entry in my database has a password field.

I want to be able to only access the page if the password is correctly entered.

I think this makes sense and I can't seem to find anything else on this other than using the built in auth functionality of Laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just setup basic auth on your webserver for this. It's really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple thing to do..

Create a form with a password field and a hidden id field where you store the id of the page you want to access.

When user submits the password, check if it matches the one in your database..

```
if (Hash::check('enetered-password', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

If so, store the page id in an array in the session. Next time the user wants to visit the page, you check if the id exists in this array, if so redirect to the page, otherwise redirect to the password form page.

It would be even wiser to add a middleware to the protected pages, to check if the user has permission or not and also redirect.

Once the session expires (i.e. use logs out) all data will be destroyed, so if they login again, they need to enter the page passwords again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go! The problem is that I need this to work without creating user accounts, that way anyone can access the page as long as they have the password.

Comment: That is not a problem at all, simply do not add the auth middleware to those routes. Also, if you'd like to limit the access, for example X minutes, just add a date/time to the array so you can check that as well.